# What is this condition?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider a $n\times m$ matrix $A$ that satisfies
$$
Ax=b
$$
for $m\times 1$ vectors $x$ and $b$. Then
$$
Ax-b=\mathbf{0}
$$
What are the conditions on $A$ so that I can write the previous system as
$$
A(x-c)=\mathbf{0}
$$
for some vector $c$ and where $Ac=b$?

If $A$ was a square matrix, it would be enough to guarantee its invertibility, since we could take $c=A^{-1}b$. I wonder what can be said in the $n\times m$ case.

Comment: Note that $b$ should be $n\times 1$ (rather than $m\times 1$).

Comment: Your question contains the answer: The sufficient and necessary condition is that there _is_ some vector $c$ such that $A c = b$, that is, that $b$ is contained in the image $\operatorname{im} A$ of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a vector $c$ with $Ac=b$, you need $b$ to be in the column space of $A$ (since an expression of the form $Ac$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.)

Comment: That is it! Thanks! If not too much trouble, would you mind taking a look at this other question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480771/understanding-a-geometric-condition this was what motivated this question, but I am struggling to see the column space in that case.